# Quip: Fetching by sections instead of threads

Tags: quip, liveapps

I'm creating a company glossary in quip and want to ping the stakeholder of a term every 6 months.

Right now I can fetch the whole doc using the thread api, but I want to fetch by section instead. Is it possible to fetch all sections of a quip document and check each section's updated_usec?

So my document might look like:

> Term 1: definition of the term. Stakeholder: PersonA
>
> Term 2: definition of the term. Stakeholder: PersonB
>
> Term 3: definition of the term. Stakeholder: PersonC

I'd like to fetch by section, so that I get something along the lines of:

```
[
  {
    html: 'Term 1: definition of the term. Stakeholder: PersonA'
    updated_usec: 123456790,
    ...
  },
  {
    html: 'Term 2: definition of the term. Stakeholder: PersonB'
    updated_usec: 123456790,
    ...
  },
  {
    html: 'Term 3: definition of the term. Stakeholder: PersonC'
    updated_usec: 123456790,
    ...
  },
]
```

Instead of by document, which would look like

```
{
  html: 'Term 1: definition of the term. Stakeholder: PersonA<br>Term 2: definition of the term. Stakeholder: PersonB<br>Term 3: definition of the term. Stakeholder: PersonC'
  updated_usec: 123456790,
  ...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The quip sdk has get_section that allows you to pull a particular section. (it basically pulls the whole thing and traverses the html tree to find your section).

https://github.com/quip/quip-api